# terminal output redirection dynamic progress bar display issue

Tags: redirect

When I redirect the terminal output to a document(In the terminal, I execute the command with `python train.py > result.txt 1>&2`.), the progress bar keeps updating instead of overwriting the previous content of the progress bar as it does in the original terminal. Do you know how I can solve this?(Here is my original code.)

def _train_epoch(self, epoch):
self.model.train()

```
    if self.method == 'supervised':
        dataloader = iter(self.supervised_loader)
        tbar = tqdm(range(len(self.supervised_loader)), ncols=160, position=0)
    else:
        dataloader = iter(zip(cycle(self.supervised_loader), self.unsupervised_loader))
        tbar = tqdm(range(len(self.unsupervised_loader)), ncols=160, position=0)

    self._reset_metrics()
    for batch_idx in tbar:
        
        .........

        if self.method == 'supervised':
            tbar.set_description('T ({}) | Ls {:.4f} Lu {:.4f} IoU(change-l) {:.3f}| '.format(
            epoch, self.loss_l.average, self.loss_ul.average, self.class_iou_l[1]))
        else:
            tbar.set_description('T ({}) | Ls: {:.4f} Lu: {:.4f} IoU(change-l): {:.3f} IoU(change-ul): {:.3f} F1(ul): {:.3f} Kappa(ul): {:.3f}|'.format(
            epoch, self.loss_l.average, self.loss_ul.average, self.class_iou_l[1], self.class_iou_ul[1], self.f1_ul, self.kappa_ul))
        
        self.lr_scheduler.step(epoch=epoch-1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDhCC.png)
I hope the output in the text is similar to the image.Instead of the progress bar being redisplayed every time it updates.